# tensorflow error KeyError: "The name 'import/Mul' refers to an Operation not in the graph."

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I did this command to check results of tensorflow training.

```
    python label_image.py --image xxx.jpg --graph retrained_graph.pb --labels retrained_labels.txt
```

And found following errors.

```
    /Users/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
      from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
    2018-07-11 00:39:22.028051: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "label_image.py", line 131, in 
        input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name)
      File "/Users/xxx/tensorFlow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3718, in get_operation_by_name
        return self.as_graph_element(name, allow_tensor=False, allow_operation=True)
      File "/Users/xxx/tensorFlow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3590, in as_graph_element
        return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
      File "/Users/xxx/tensorFlow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3650, in _as_graph_element_locked
        "graph." % repr(name))
    KeyError: "The name 'import/Mul' refers to an Operation not in the graph."
```

label_image.py is following lines.

```
      input_height = 299
      input_width = 299
      input_mean = 0
      input_std = 255
      input_layer = "Mul"
      output_layer = "final_result"
```

Comment: python label_image.py --image cat3.jpg --graph retrained_graph.pb --labels retrained_labels.txt --input_layer=Placeholder

This command, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

python label_image.py --image cat3.jpg --graph retrained_graph.pb --labels retrained_labels.txt --input_layer=Placeholder

This command, the problem was solved.